# How to search for a word inside all the Java classes from target in Intellij generated after mvn build?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, search

I'm learning Java with Maven projects using Intellij, and when I run `mvn clean install`, it creates the target directory and inside target, there is WEB-INF...

I want to ask you how can I search for a word inside all the classes from target directory, inside all the WEB-INF.

To search for a word in Intellij inside src\main\java I'm using CTRL + SHIFT +F, but this command doesn't work to search inside target\WEB-INF...

I have a lot of classes generated from mvn build, and these classes aren't int the src\main\java and I want to ask you how to search inside them?

Thank you!

Comment: The question why you like to search in `target` directory because the words must be in your source code or express it different. In your `src/main/` directory ?

Comment: You can configure the search in IntellIJ in the upper right corner of the search box there is a filter symbol ... check that...

Answer (score 2):

In intellij Idea, press **SHIFT** key twice and enter the keyword to search.

In case of Eclipse, click on Search menu then search and select scope as Workspace, find below the image.

[image]

Comment: I'm using Intellij and I tried using SHIFT key twice, but it deosn't work for a word, it works to search a class or interface.

Comment: Then please update to latest version of Intellij Idea.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a development enviroment are just folders.

If you are using linux you can use:

`grep -R "content_to_search" /path/to/directory`

A quick search on windows should find you the answer.

Comment: It was asked to search in IDEA IntelliJ not on command line...